# Which Authorize.net API's are used in Magento?

Tags: magento-enterprise, payment-gateway, authorize.net

Magento has two relevant payment methods:  Authorize.net and Authorize.net Direct Post.  My assumption is that the Authorize.net method uses the AIM api, and the Authorize.net Direct Post uses the DPM api.

A comparison of the Authorize.net APIs can be found here:  http://developer.authorize.net/api/compare/

The code seems to support my assumption based on these two models:

```
Mage_Authorizenet_Model_Directpost
Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet
```

Can anyone confirm/deny this assumption?

Comment: I'm using Magento EE v 1.13.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Paygate uses AIM and the Directpost uses Directpost API.  You can confirm this yourself by looking at the code for the two implementations.  The Authorizenet module has a controller and implementation for the responses expected by Authorize.net's Directpost API.  The Authorize.net paygate implementation doesn't have a controller to receive responses from the Authorize.net API.